# Click to add class and click again to remove class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, syntax

I got a problem with my javascript code . I want to have a function that if I click the class or a id , it will add css class so the ui will different if the button is clicked , and I want to make it look like normal when the button click again . This is my code

```js
function Menu(e) {
  let list = document.querySelector('ul');
  e.name === 'menu' ? (e.name = "close", list.classList.add('top-[80px]'), list.classList.add('opacity-100')) : 
                      (e.name = "menu", list.classList.remove('top-[80px]'), list.classList.remove('opacity-100'))
  if (e) {
    $('.navbar').addClass("sticky-costum-2");
  } else {
    $('.navbar').removeClass("sticky-costum-2");
  }
};
```

the context is I want to make my navbar look bigger when user click the burger button , so it will add class
"sticky-costum-2" to make it bigger .

but the problem is , if I click again to close the burger button , it not remove the class , I know that I'm wrong but I'm newbie. I recently have same kind of problem in my last project and this is my code

```
var b = document.getElementById("button");
      var audio = document.getElementById("player");
    
      
      b.addEventListener("click", function(){
        if(audio.paused){
          
          audio.play();
          audio.loop='true';
          b.innerHTML = "<img class='sticky' src ='https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/0/375.png'>";
        } else {
          audio.pause();
          b.innerHTML = "<img class='sticky' src ='https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/933/PNG/512/rounded-pause-button_icon-icons.com_72587.png' >";
        }
      });
```

Yea it's an audio player and it works , it can play and pause the audio in the same button , but I have no idea how I can implement this my code to fix my problem .

Comment: you looking for `classList.toggle`

Comment: or in jQuery: .toggleClass

Comment: Native JS or jQuery? Because it looks like you're only using jQuery for about 3% of that code. Maybe stick with one or the other. Native JS [already has a toggle method for the classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Comment: `const list = document.querySelector('ul');
const navBar = document.querySelector('.navbar');
const Menu = (e) => { list.classList.toggle('open'); navBar.classList.toggle('sticky-costum-2'); };`

Comment: if you don't wanna use toggle you can use  this  $(".navbar").hasClass("sticky-costum-2") ? $('.navbar').removeClass("sticky-costum-2") : $('.navbar').addClass("sticky-costum-2");        OR         if ($(".navbar").hasClass("sticky-costum-2")) {
            $('.navbar').removeClass("sticky-costum-2");
        } else {
            $('.navbar').addClass("sticky-costum-2");
        }

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your problem but it has what has helped me. Instead of styling in the javascript do the styling in the css. What I am saying is when you add the class in the css select that class even though it doesn't exist right now it will exist when you click it. When you remove the class go to the css and check for the normal element or class you had originally. This might solve your problem.